# How to delete an undeletable file?

Tags: macos, alias

I have removed the Transmit app (ftp program) by drag and drop it to my trash including the other files of the application in the Library folder `~/Library` and empty the trash.

Then I found out that there is a file was not thrown away, which is 'com.panic.transmit.sfl'. I tried to delete this file to, but when I want to drag it to the trash, the trash will be changing to an eject arrow icon.

When I double click the file, I have to options: delete alias - this doesn't do anything - or recover alias - that will open a dialog where you can select a file - but I don't know which file should connected to it.

Also the file doesn't have a path, but when I search in `~/Library` for `transmit` the file appears in the finder.

I try to download and install Transmit again. Than there is also a new 'com.panic.transmit.sfl' file created, tha can be deleted, but still the other one is visible.

Is there a way to delete undeletable files?

[image]
[image: Doubble click the icon will give to options, described above]

Comment: It's working. I notice that I doesn't add Macintosh HD to the list. The instructions below are working. @patrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to try in these cases is to remove it via Terminal:

- Open Terminal
- Type `rm` followed by a space
- Drag the file into the Terminal window (wait for the green + sign to appear, then release the mouse button) -> Path to file should get added in the Terminal window
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Based on your additional information it seems to be phantom file only "known" to Spotlight. To rebuild the Spotlight index, either see [Apple's support article on the topic](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716) or run

```
sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD
```

in Terminal.

Comment: Not working. I'm not able to drag the file. When I will drag it, the trash immediately changes in an eject arrow. Also tried to rename it, but that's not allowed.. The path is also not shown in the finder. I am only be able to double click it and recover the alias or delete the alias. Last one doesn't work and the first one, I don't know which file I should find than..

Answer (score 0):

Are you dragging to the Terminal window Caspert, or the trash? I don't have the reputation to reply to patrix's comment but you could also rm the full filename while inside the directory, eg.

```
cd /Library/path_to_file_you_want_to_delete
rm file_you_want_to_delete
```

Comment: I tried both, but aren't able to drag it in the trash or terminal. The problem is that the file doesn't have a path... When I install the program again, the file is located in `/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments` but only the new installed version will add the file to that folder. That file I can delete and edit etc.. If there is a way to know the alias of that file, than I can fix the alias of the other file I think. Or is there another way to delete undeletable files?

Comment: If I search for the file in finder, I must select Library for the search area, otherwise the file isn't located.

Comment: Can you enter into a terminal window:

    `sudo find / -name com.panic.transmit.sfl`

and post the output?